# How to iterate the elements and based on certain condition update the entries an object in React Js

Tags: reactjs

I have one requirement. Here, doing iterate over list Object elements , based on condition need to set/update new values in that Object list.

List Object is like below,
previewValues = [{"DATE": "5/1/2020",  "X" : "", "Y": ""}, {"DATE": "5/1/2020",  "X" : "3", "Y": "4"}] .

Here, I need to iterate over the previewValues and while iterate check if Date= 5/1/2020 and at same time other elements(X,Y) key's values are "" / NA then update those key's values to 1 otherwise leave as it is.

Please find the code snippet below. Here , I am just ignoring DATE element and update other elements.

```
previewValues.forEach(value => {
      Object.entries(value).forEach(([key]) => {
        if (key !== 'DATE' && (value[key] === '' || value[key] === 'NA')) {
          value[key] = 0;
        }
      });
      result.push(value);
    });
```

The above code only updates simply 0's, it is not checking the DATE condition.

Answer (score 0):

A map is the better implementation here:

```
const previewValues = [{"DATE": "5/1/2020", "X" : "", "Y": ""}, {"DATE": "5/1/2020", "X" : "3", "Y": "4"}];

const isEmptyString = (value) => value === "" || value==="NA";
const updatedObjects = previewValues.map(item => {
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(item)) {
    if(key !== 'DATE') {
      if(isEmptyString(value)) item[key]=1
    }   
  }
 return item;
})
console.log(updatedObjects)
// Outputs:  [{ DATE: "5/1/2020", X: 1, Y: 1 }, { DATE: "5/1/2020", X: "3", Y: "4" }]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but here slight changes are required. Actually the DATE field values will differ like 5/1/2020, 4/1/2020, 3/1/2020 dynamically . Here we need to do update only for Max. DATE and also for that DATE other elements are ""/NA then only  need to update 1 otherwise leave as it is.

Comment: Note: Don't Ignore DATE Field, based on Max.DATE condition we need to update other values.

Comment: You realize that's not part of your question?